# Ошибка в Python в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import pygame as pg
import telebot

TOKEN = "..."

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_t(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['audio'])
def music_c(message):
    if message.text == 'Big Rocky - Freestyle [Drift]':
        pygame.init()
        song = pygame.mixer.Sound('Big Rocky - Freestyle [ Drift ]')
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        song.play()
    while True:
        clock.tick(50)
    pygame.quit()

bot.polling()
```

ошибка:UnboundLocalError: local variable 'clock' referenced before assignment

Comment: В чем ошибка то?  Приложите текст сообщения об ошибке

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'clock' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1):

Переменная присваивается в `if` что может и не произойти, но откуда она берется тогда во `while`?
Переписал код по идее должно все работать.

```py
import pygame
import pygame as pg
import telebot

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['audio'])
def music_c(message):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() # добавлено
    if message.text == 'Big Rocky - Freestyle [Drift]':
        pygame.init()
        song = pygame.mixer.Sound('Big Rocky - Freestyle [ Drift ]')
        # Убрано
        song.play()
    while True:
        clock.tick(50)
    pygame.quit()
```